# Magento: Invalid method Mage_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option_Radio

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.4

I see the following error when opening the page of one of our shop items. In the current template it doesn't work, in another plain template it does. The problem may be caused by an upgrade from magento 1.4 to 1.7.

Can anyone explain what this means and what is happening? How can I fix this?

`a:5:{i:0;s:109:"Invalid method Mage_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option_Radio::_getDefaultValues(Array
(
)
)";i:1;s:7069:"#0 /www/htdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/radio.phtml(33): Varien_Object->__call('_getDefaultValu...', Array)`

Below the complete error report. The product is part of a bundle.

```
a:5:{i:0;s:109:"Invalid method Mage_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option_Radio::_getDefaultValues(Array
(
)
)";i:1;s:7069:"#0 /www/htdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/radio.phtml(33): Varien_Object->__call('_getDefaultValu...', Array)

#1 /www/htdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/radio.phtml(33): Mage_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option_Radio->_getDefaultValues()
#2 /www/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/www/ht...')
#3 /www/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
#4 /www/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#5 /www/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Price.php(154): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#6 /www/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Block/Catalog/Product/Price.php(97): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Price->_toHtml()
#7 /www/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_Price->_toHtml()
#8 /www/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Block/Catalog/Product/View/Type/Bundle.php(216): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#9 /www/htdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/options.phtml(37): Mage_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle->getOptionHtml(Object(Mage_Bundle_Model_Option))
#10 /www/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/www/ht...')
#11 /www/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
#12 /www/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#13 /www/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#14 /www/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 /www/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(522): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('product.info.bu...', true)
#16 /www/htdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml(28): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('', true, true)
#17 /www/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/www/ht...')
#18 /www/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
#19 /www/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#20 /www/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#21 /www/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#22 /www/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(522): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('product.info.op...', true)
#23 /www/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(546): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('', true, true)
#24 /www/htdocs/app/design/frontend/default/shoestore/template/catalog/product/view.phtml(101): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true)
#25 /www/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/www/ht...')
#26 /www/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#27 /www/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#28 /www/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#29 /www/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#30 /www/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#31 /www/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#32 /www/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#32 /www/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#33 /www/htdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/2columns-right.phtml(48): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#34 /www/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/www/ht...')
#35 /www/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
#36 /www/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#37 /www/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#38 /www/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#39 /www/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#40 /www/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#41 /www/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'no-route')
#42 /www/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(75): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'no-route')
#43 /www/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Cms_IndexController->noRouteAction()
#44 /www/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('noRoute')
#45 /www/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#46 /www/htdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#47 /www/htdocs/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#48 /www/htdocs/index.php(119): Mage::run('', 'store')
#49 {main}";s:3:"url";s:26:"/nike-bw-black.html";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

The code of the phtml file: http://pastebin.com/6CGq3nSR

Comment: Something on that page you are loading uses radio buttons in a form and something related to that isn't working. As in, the default radio button that is set to be selected is not appearing in the form containing the options. Perhaps it is product options? Who knows. You would receive more help if you provided a link to where this is happening or more information.

Comment: Thank you. I added the complete error report. I've noticed that this error doesn't appear when using another template.

Comment: Paste the phtml file content here please

Comment: I tried to paste the phtml code, but that doesn't work properly as you can see. I've used <pre> tags around it. Here you can see how it should look: http://pastebin.com/6CGq3nSR

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you have mismatched code from different version of Magento running in your system.  It's also possible you have a compiled version of an old class, or a community/local code pool override. This is going to be long, so I'll try to call out the specific debugging tips **with bold text**

As the other answers have made clear, PHP is telling you the exact problem.

> Mage_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option_Radio::_getDefaultValues

Magento is trying to call the `_getDefaultValues` method on your `Mage_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option_Radio` object. However, in **your** system, this object doesn't have this method.  If I look at a fresh install of Magento 1.7.0.1 , this class is defined in

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Block/Catalog/Product/View/Type/Bundle/Option/Radio.php
class Mage_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option_Radio
    extends Mage_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option
{
    /**
     * Set template
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->setTemplate('bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/radio.phtml');
    }
}
```

and in its parent class `Mage_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option`, we can find the definition of `_getDefaultValues`

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Block/Catalog/Product/View/Type/Bundle/Option.php
class Mage_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option extends Mage_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_Price
{
    protected function _getDefaultValues()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Protected methods are callable from a block's template, so this means this is **not** a bug with the shipping version of Magento, but is instead a problem with your system.

**Debugging Step 1**: The first thing to check would be your version of the file

```
app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Block/Catalog/Product/View/Type/Bundle/Option.php
```

Does this file have a `_getDefaultValues` method?  If not, of if it's `private` instead of `protected`, then the problem is your version of the `phtml` template is from one version of Magento, but your core class file is from another, or has been modified.  You could try downloading a fresh copy of the Magento version you're running and replacing the file — but your system may have other problems if this was a botched upgrade, so be ready for that.  Fixing that is larger than a single Stack Overflow question.

**Debugging Step 2**: Check your local and community code pools.

Magento allows you to replace class files by using the `app/code/community` and `app/code/local` code pools.  Your system may have a version of this class file that's in one of these pools.  Check for a file in

```
app/code/community/Mage/Bundle/Block/Catalog/Product/View/Type/Bundle/Option.php
app/code/local/Mage/Bundle/Block/Catalog/Product/View/Type/Bundle/Option.php
```

and if there's a file, check for the `_getDefaultValues` method.  If it's not there, or if it's `private` instead of `protected`, you've found your problem.  Fixing this will, again, be tricky.  If the file was placed here it means a previous developer added or changed methods.  You could fix your error above by removing the `local` or `community` file, but then you'd lose this custom functionality.  You'll need to merge a correct `core` file in with your `local`/`community` file OR you'll need to identify the extra functionality in your `local`/`community` file and refactor these to use class rewrites, and only then remove the file.  Again, that's a process that's more complicated than a single stack overflow answer.

**Debugging Step 3**: Turn off compilation.

It's also possible that Magento is running in "compiled" mode, and that the "compiled" version of your class.  Turn off compilation mode from

```
System -> Tools -> Compilation
```

or from the command line with

```
$ php shell/compiler.php disable
```

and recompile you classes.

**Debugging Step 4**: Clear opt code cache.

If you're running a system like APC to cache PHP opt code, it may be an old version of the class is in the opt code cache.  As there's numerous options here, I'll leave the clearing of this cache as an exercise for the reader.

**Debugging Step 5**: Use reflection to identify the class file

If you still haven't identified the rouge class at this point, add the following code to the bottom of `index.php`

```
$o = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->createBlock('bundle/catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_radio');
$r = new ReflectionClass($o);
echo '<h1>';
var_dump(get_class($o));
var_dump($r->getFilename());
echo '</h1>';
```

This will instantiate a block class and use reflection to tell you where it's definition file is.  From there, you can figure out why this is the wrong definition file, and what you'll need to do to remove it.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for this long reply! This installation is upgraded from 1.4 to 1.7 a while ago. Debugging step 1: the method is protected, so this is not the problem. Step 3: compilation is turned off. Step 4: clearing the cache; I've done this in the admin, but not on the server if that makes a difference. STEP 2: The method is not there, so this is the problem, according to your explanation. The community file doesn't exist, but local does, without the method. I guess step 5 is not relevant now. I can post a new question about step 2.

Comment: Also check that you aren't redeclaring/over writing the same name of an above instantiated class.

Answer (score 2):

You seems to be calling a non existing method on an object of type `Mage_[...]_Radio`.

The class `Mage_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option_Radio` [does not have](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Bundle/Mage_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option_Radio.html) any public method called `_getDefaultValues`.

---

After a little bit of research I've found that the method [actually exists](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Bundle/Mage_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option.html#_getDefaultValues) in that class but its visibility is protected therefore to access it you inherit from the `Mage_[...]_Radio` class and make it public accessible or leave it protected:

```
class YourClass extends Mage_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option_Radio {
    public function getDefaultValues() { return $this->_getDefaultValues(); }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. But still I don't understand how to solve this. The file that calls this method is located in app/design/frontend/base/default, so part of the base template from Magento. Does this mean the base template has a bug? NB: I'll renew the bounty after it expires!

Comment: @rxt, watch the edit. Unfortunately I cannot get my hands on the source code. Can you show the part of the code that is triggering this error?

Comment: @rxt, yeah it is wrong. Is this provided by Magento as it is?